# PHPUnit Tests in Laravel Fail when using 2 or more Methods

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

So I have a very peculiar problem with my unit tests in laravel. What I am trying to do is some basic unit testing, and so I have a single class set up with my tests. The tests worked perfectly when I had a single method that ran tests. The class looked like so:

```
class Pixel_BasicTest extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase {


public function createApplication()
{
    $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
    $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel')->bootstrap();
    return $app;
}

public function testRoutes(){
    echo "Start of testRoutes\n";

    //Test all the GET routes we have
    $routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();
    $num_404s = 0;
    $path_404s = [];
    ...various other code that does some tests, these all work right
}
}
```

Now, the problem occurs when I try to add another function. My class now looks like this:

```
class Pixel_BasicTest extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase {


public function createApplication()
{
    $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
    $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel')->bootstrap();
    return $app;
}

public function testRoutes(){
    echo "Start of testRoutes\n";

    //Test all the GET routes we have
    $routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();
    $num_404s = 0;
    $path_404s = [];
    ...various other code that does some tests, these all work right
}

public function testSecondThing() {
    echo "Start of testSecondThing";
    ...some code testing something else
}


}
```

Now, I know that the code from the 2nd function works, because when I put that code in the first function, and remove the 2nd function entirely, the tests run perfectly. However, when I put the code in a second function, it fails, and my terminal window looks like this:

```
Mikes-MacBook-Air-96:hq pixelmember$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit -v --debug
PHPUnit 4.8.29 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:    PHP 5.6.10
Configuration:  /Users/pixelmember/Documents/hq/phpunit.xml


Starting test 'Pixel_BasicTest::testRoutes'.
.Start of testRoutes
End of testRoutes

Starting test 'Pixel_BasicTest::testAfterschool'.
Mikes-MacBook-Air-96:hq pixelmember$
```

As you can see, it gets to the 2nd function, and just stops or fails or something. There is no error message, and I also don't see the message I wrote in the code at the start of the function (The echo "Starting testSecondThing()" part)

I'm honestly at a loss for what to do. I can make do without the unit tests for now, and can work on some other parts of my application, but I really want to be able to use unit tests without having to stick every single one of my tests in a single function.

In case it helps, here is my phpunit.xml file. Perhaps someone can see something in here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
     colors="true"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnFailure="false"
     syntaxCheck="false">
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <file>./tests/Pixel_BasicTest.php</file>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
<filter>
    <blacklist>
        <directory>./vendor</directory>
    </blacklist>
</filter>
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="test"/>
    <env name="DB_USERNAME" value="root"/>
    <env name="DB_PASSWORD" value=""/>
</php>
```

I didn't really edit or change much of this file, besides adding some database related environment variables.

**EDIT: I FIXED MY ISSUE, SEE BELOW FOR FIX**

Answer (score 4):

Wow I actually just figured it out. Sometimes it just takes taking a break then haha.

In case someone needs help with a similar problem, what I did to fix my issue was change my phpunit.xml file. I changed the setting "processIsolation" to true, so my phpunit.xml file now looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
      backupStaticAttributes="false"
      bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
      colors="true"
      convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
      convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
      convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
      processIsolation="true"
      stopOnFailure="false"
      syntaxCheck="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <file>./tests/Pixel_BasicTest.php</file>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <blacklist>
            <directory>./vendor</directory>
        </blacklist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="test"/>
        <env name="DB_USERNAME" value="root"/>
        <env name="DB_PASSWORD" value=""/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

I'm still curious why exactly this works, and what exactly this setting does? I know that this runs each test in a seperate PHP process, but I am unsure why this helps/fixes the issue, and if this truely fixed my issue or if I will run into more problems later on.

If someone with more experience with PHPUnit could shed some light on this that would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Some links to the documentation I used:
phpunit.xml config file:
https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html
definition of some of the settings:
https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions